# How do I enable language-specific syntax inside a heredoc?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-php

When I edit a PHP file and I define a string in a heredoc, syntax highlighting will be enabled inside the heredoc if it is JavaScript syntax or HTML syntax or SQL syntax. However it will not work for CSS syntax.

Example (if we create a new PHP file called `hello.php` with the following code):

```php
<?php
$foo = <<<"JAVASCRIPT"
var hello = "hello";
JAVASCRIPT;

$bar = <<<"CSS"
/* This code below should be syntax-highlighted. */
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
}
CSS;
```

The `JAVASCRIPT` block is highlighted correctly, but the `CSS` block is not. Also, if I run `SynStack` on the `var` keyword on the JavaScript code block, I get `['phpRegion', 'phpHereDoc', 'javaScriptIdentifier']`, but if I do the same to any place in the CSS block, I only get `['phpRegion', 'phpHereDoc']`, so I need to add some CSS syntax highlighting rules. Where are these syntax rules getting defined, and how do I add to them?

Comment: Note: `// This should be syntax-highlighted` is not a valid CSS comment, and so should be syntax highlighted as something other than a comment. CSS only supports `/* */` multi-line comments. `//` single-line comments are only supported if you use preprocessor languages such as Sass or Stylus.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the code to reflect that change.

Comment: I too am looking to get a solution for CSS heredoc syntax highlighting.  I tried many scenarios but could not get it to work.  Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR:

It's defined in Vim's PHP and HTML syntax files. To see how to add rules for CSS, jump to the section **And how do I add to them?** below, or read on for an explanation of how it works.

### Where are these syntax rules getting defined?

The JavaScript heredoc is highlighted using Vim's syntax `contains`<sup>1</sup> feature, which allows syntax groups to contain other syntax groups.

To find where this is defined, first open up the syntax highlighting file for PHP:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim
```

Now, presumably the syntax file is finding the JavaScript heredoc based on a match of the string "javascript", so lets try searching for that:

```
/javascript
```

The third match is this comment:

```
" including HTML,JavaScript,SQL even if not enabled via options
```

Looks promising! Let's take a look at the relevant syntax line:

```
syn region  phpHereDoc  matchgroup=Delimiter
\ start="\(<<<\)\@<=\(\"\=\)\z(\(\I\i*\)\=\(javascript\)\c\(\i*\)\)\2$"
\ end="^\z1\(;\=$\)\@="
\ contained
\ contains=@htmlJavascript,phpIdentifierSimply,phpIdentifier,phpIdentifierComplex,phpBackslashSequences,phpMethodsVar,@Spell
\ keepend extend
```

(*line continuations added for easier reading*)

Okay, so this syntax region finds the JavaScript heredoc with a convoluted regular expression, and allows JavaScript highlighting within the region by including the `@htmlJavascript` syntax `cluster`<sup>2</sup> within the `contains` argument.

But there is no corresponding definition for CSS heredocs! Lets add one. So the first thing to change is the `start` regular expression. Simply change the `javascript` into `css`:

```
start="\(<<<\)\@<=\(\"\=\)\z(\(\I\i*\)\=\(css\)\c\(\i*\)\)\2$"
```

This is easy!

But we don't want JavaScript highlighting in our CSS heredoc. So we also need to change the `@htmlJavascript` to the CSS equivalent. But what *is* the CSS equivalent? (You might be able to guess, but let's go through the motions to be sure.)

Lets search for `htmljavascript`<sup>3</sup> to see where that is defined:

```
/htmljavascript
```

Hmmm. No other results. It must be defined elsewhere! Let's have a quick look at the top of the file to see if we can find any includes:

```
runtime! syntax/html.vim
```

This looks like it could be it<sup>4</sup>.

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim
```

Run the search again in this file, and we find this line<sup>5</sup>:

```
syn cluster htmlJavaScript      add=@htmlPreproc
```

So htmlJavaScript is a `cluster`, defined in `html.vim`. Is there a similar cluster for CSS we can use?

```
/htmlcss
```

Yup!

```
syn include @htmlCss syntax/css.vim
```

So we just need to replace `@htmlJavascript` with `@htmlCss` in the `contains` argument:

```
contains=@htmlCss,phpIdentifierSimply,phpIdentifier,[...]
```

### And how do I add to them?

Save the entire syntax command below in the file `~/after/syntax/php.vim` so that it is run after the rest of the PHP syntax processing has been carried out, and you're done!

```
syn region  phpHereDoc  matchgroup=Delimiter
\ start="\(<<<\)\@<=\(\"\=\)\z(\(\I\i*\)\=\(css\)\c\(\i*\)\)\2$"
\ end="^\z1\(;\=$\)\@="
\ contained
\ contains=@htmlCss,phpIdentifierSimply,phpIdentifier,phpIdentifierComplex,phpBackslashSequences,phpMethodsVar,@Spell
\ keepend extend
```

<sub>1: See `:help :syn-contains` for details.

2: See `:help :syn-cluster`.

3: I've got `'ignorecase'` switched on. Without it, you'll need to search for `htmlJavascript` or `\chtmljavascript`

4: In fact, based on the naming scheme used in Vim syntax files, we probably could have figured this out based on the `htmlJavascript` name alone.

5: With "JavaScript" capitalised differently, this time. Lucky we've got `'ignorecase'` switched on, eh?</sub>